# Save procedure to file

Tags: list, vector, save, tcl, puts

I am starting to learn TCL languages so the question might be a little simple. I am looking to construct a matrix from vector. I found the following idea looking into previously asked question :

```
 set phi_x [lrepeat 36 [lrepeat 12 0.]]
```

To create my list of vector. Then I populate the vector of the list with the command lset. I then use the following, which I found on another question threads :

```
proc printMatrix {myMatrix} {

set height [llength [lindex $myMatrix]]
set width [llength [lindex $myMatrix 0]]
for {set j 0} {$j < $width} {incr j} {
    puts -nonewline \Phi$j
}
puts ""
for {set i 0} {$i < $height} {incr i} {
    puts -nonewline $i
    for {set j 0} {$j < $width} {incr j} {
        puts -nonewline \t[lindex $myMatrix $i $j]
    }
    puts ""
}
```

This code works fine. Problem is I cannot seems to save the result of the procedure into a file using the

```
set varName [open file.out a]
puts $varName [printMatrix $myMatrix]
close $varName
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your procedure doesn't seem to be returning any value, in which case the empty string will be written to the file. The `puts` statements will only affect standard output, not the file.

Comment: The procedure return, at screen, the values of the vector contained in the list previously defined. The list is created using 
set phi_x [lrepeat 36 [lrepeat 12 0.]]
"myMatrix" is "phi_x"... sorry for the confusion =(

Comment: The procedure doesn't end with a command that returns any value. I presume you are running the procedure in a shell and observing the output from the `puts` invocations. Output is not the same as return value.

Comment: I followed your comment and edited the procedure as follow :
proc printMatrix {phi_x} {
set fox [open Modx.out a]   
 set height [llength [lindex $phi_x]]
    set width [llength [lindex $phi_x 0]]
    for {set j 0} {$j < $width} {incr j} {
        puts -nonewline $fox \Phi$j
    }
    puts ""
    for {set i 0} {$i < $height} {incr i} {
       puts -nonewline $fox $i
        for {set j 0} {$j < $width} {incr j} {
         puts -nonewline $fox \t[lindex $phi_x $i $j]
        }
        puts ""
 }
 }
It seems to be working!

Comment: You still have a few problems there, including still outputting the newlines to `stdout` rather than `$fox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return a value from the procedure and print it, like this

```
puts $varName [printMatrix $myMatrix]
```

then you need to replace the `puts -nonewline ...` invocations with `append res ...`, and the `puts ""` invocations by `append res \n`, and finally, when the procedure is done, call `return $res`.

If you want the procedure to output text to a file, call it like this

```
printMatrix $varName $myMatrix
```

and redefine it like this

```
proc printMatrix {chan myMatrix} {
```

replacing `puts -nonewline ...` with `puts -nonewline $chan ...` and `puts ""` with `puts $chan ""`.

Documentation: [append](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/append.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [return](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm)

Comment: Very sorry, I did not know I had to do this... very sorry =(

Comment: @John: you don't *have* to do it, it's your choice whether to accept or not. But accepting the answer 1) attests that it is useful, which is interesting for others looking for answers to the same question, 2) removes the question from the list of open questions, and 3) gives me 15 rep ;)